# External URL in Nav menu not working

Tags: javascript, html, nav

I'm trying to get a menu link to redirect as target=_blank but it just won't seem to work. It works if I put this code in its own html file, but not when it is on my site

It is the "Example" menu link I am having trouble with.

```
<!-- Nav -->
  <nav id="navigation" class="animated fadeInUpBig shadow">
    <ul id="nav">
      <li class="current shadow"><a href="#section-1">Home</a></li>
      <li class="shadow"><a href="#section-2">About</a></li>
      <li class="shadow"><a href="#section-3">Services</a></li>
      <li class="shadow"><a href="#section-4">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Example</a></li>
      <li class="shadow"><a href="#section-6">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Here is everything that mentions target in my JS

```
getHash: function($link) {
            return $link.attr('href').split('#')[1];
        },

getPositions: function() {
            var self = this;
            var linkHref;
            var topPos;
            var $target;

            self.$nav.each(function() {
                linkHref = self.getHash($(this));
                $target = $('#' + linkHref);

                if($target.length) {
                    topPos = $target.offset().top;
                    self.sections[linkHref] = Math.round(topPos) - self.config.scrollOffset;

handleClick: function(e) {
            var self = this;
            var $link = $(e.currentTarget);
            var $parent = $link.parent();
            var newLoc = '#' + self.getHash($link);
```

Comment: Any JavaScript, that'd remove the `target` attribute?

Comment: I'm looking through my jquery.nav.js now, anything I should keep any eye out for?

Comment: Before rushing to dive into the code, fire up your browser's developer tools and take a look at that element there. `target` there? `href` there and unchanged? Any event handlers registered?

Comment: Is that the whole handleClick function?  It looks like it is manipulating the link in the last line - can you show us the getHash function too?

Comment: Everything on the element is as it should be online (I can open the link by right clicking and selecting open in new tab. Haha)
I'm not too clued up with JS and event handlers, should I look into this?

Comment: Hey Jen, I had added getHash.

Thanks for attempting to help me out here all.

Comment: There must be an event handler that is doing something to alter the behavior of your links. The easiest way to see that is as @Boldewyn suggested - use your browser's dev tools to see what is going on

Comment: Not so complicated! It's the getHash function, that is applied to _all_ nav points. In the case of an URL without `#` it just returns the empty string == the current page's URL. `handleClick()` just needs to check, if `link.href` starts with a hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search for those function names leads me to believe that you are using [jQuery-One-Page-Nav](https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav) - that is meant as navigation for a single page website with only internal links.
According to the readme file for jQuery-One-Page-Nav, you need to add a class named "external" to the link in order to get an external page link to work:

```
<li><a href="http://google.com" class="external">Some other link</a></li>
```

Popping that into a new tab should be a simple adjustment from there:

```
<li><a href="http://www.google.com" class="external" target="_blank">Example</a></li>
```

Comment: Jen, you are the greatest person on the planet in my eyes right now. (Can't believe the answer was so simple. A mistake I shall not make again) 
Thank you!

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you. :-)